# pandas: force index `dtype` in `DataFrame.from_records`?

Tags: python, pandas

When pandas `Index` constructor is given a list of `datetime` objects, it creates a `DatetimeIndex`. However, when it is given a list of `date` objects, it creates instead a generic `Index` of `dtype=object`.

When manually creating the dataframe, one can force pandas to use the appropriate index by explicitly passing `index = DatetimeIndex(dates_list)`.

However, when I'm using the `Dataframe.from_records` constructor, is there any way to set the index type to `DatetimeIndex`?

Comment: What is a `DataFrameIndex`??

Comment: @wwii: typo. meant `DatetimeIndex`